# PHP Problem reading the hex values between these addresses?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$file = 'file.dat';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
for ($i = 0x000481; $i <= 0x00048B; $i++) {
print $i;
}
?>
```

I am creating an online file analyzer but I have a small problem. It outputs (which is the actual position the hex is in)

> 1153 1154 1155 1156 1157 1158 1159 1160 1161 1162 1163

when it should be

> 44 72 48 79 64 72 61 6C 69 73 6B

which his hex for DrHydralisk (me). Can anyone help me output the latter or just have it strait output ASCII (but hex is fine, I can just convert it)?

**edit**

Here is an image of what I am trying to do that I think will help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TORd3.png

Here is the file I am trying to read, its a Starcraft replay (file.SC2Replay). Just search for DrHydralisk in a hex editor and that is where I am trying to read from.

http://www.mediafire.com/?6w8wi35q3o6ix8q

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. These numbers x841 and above are 'positions of characters in the file'?

Comment: i don't see how $i in the loop has anything to do with the file contents. show us the entire code.

Comment: That is the entire code. What I am trying to do is read what is in between 0x000481 and 0x00048B. Instead of returning 44 (which is hex for D) it returns 1153 which is the location of 44 in the file (1153 out of 18051).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be (if clear text is in the file):

```
for( $i=0x481; $i<0x48D; $i++ ) {
   printf("%X ", ord($file_contents[$i]));
}
```

Note the loop boundaries: 0x481  .. 0x48D

Result:

```
44 72 20 48 79 64 72 61 6C 69 73 6B
```

If the file contains hexadecimal numbers, this would be impossible because you need two bytes per hex char for the ascii character value range. So what **is really** in the file?

---

**Edit**

After reading your file, i did:

```
...

$file = 'file.SC2Replay';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

for( $i=0x438; $i<0x443; $i++) {
   printf("%X ", ord($file_contents[$i]));
}
 for( $i=0x438; $i<0x443; $i++) {
   printf("%s ", $file_contents[$i]);
}

...
```

And it says:

```
72 48 79 64 72 61 6C 69 73 6B
```

and

```
D r H y d r a l i s k
```

You messed up the file position ;-)

Regards

rbo

Comment: That only returns a bunch of 0's

Comment: Dr Hydralisk, I created a file where i put your name in ASCII text at position 0x481 and it worked as advertised ;-) can you please include your file somehow (in <blockquote>) in your posting (use: edit)

Comment: Thanks, I actually just got it working before I read your post. My original for loop was pointless because it was not even looping through the actual file. Thanks, your a life saver :D

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Thanks for providing the file, helped a lot! Beleive I got it working too:

```
//Do binary safe file read
$filename = 'file.SC2Replay';
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);

//position 1080 - 1091
for ($i = 0x438; $i < 0x443; $i++)
    echo $contents[$i];
```

The reasons you were probably having problems is that first of all, a binary safe file read in php automatically replaces the bytes with the correct ASCII characters, so that threw off what position you actually needed to start reading from. Intead of 1153, it starts at 1080.

---

Could you explain how you are using the file you read in? Because the hex equivalent of:

```
11531154115511561157115811591160116111621163
```

is:

```
481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 48a 48b
```

Also, there are two php functions you may find helpful

chr(int): returns the ascii character associated with the integer provided - http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

dechex(int): returns the hex value of the integer provided - http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

Comment: 1153 1154 1155 1156 1157 1158 1159 1160 1161 1162 1163

This is the position of each hex value in the file (44 is at 1153, 72 is at 1154, 48 is at 1155, etc).

Comment: Can you please provide us with at least a similar file? It's very hard to help you otherwise